# Understanding the Beck-Chevalley condition (II)

Tags: category-theory, simplex, simplicial-stuff, higher-category-theory

The older [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2200469/239005) here on the site asks about the intuitive meaning of the [Beck-Chevalley condition](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Beck-Chevalley+condition). Accidentally [one of the answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2201201/239005) has caught my eye.

It made me wonder if it is possible to describe the Beck-Chevalley condition geometrically, by means of simplices. In particular I mean e.g to describe the Beck-Chevalley condition in a similar way a Kan complex is defined in terms of a [filling condition](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Kan+complex), i.e. somethings extend to simplices.

P.S. It seems the question took little of attention, should I try to reformulate it somehow? Any suggestions are welcome.

P.P.S. By somethings extend to simplices I mean something like:
Kan condition (extension to tetrahedron): If three 2-dimensional triangles are such that any two share the 1-dimensional boundary, than there is a 3-dimensional simplex filling the gap extending them to a tetrahedron.

[image]

Beck-Chevalley condition: If two 2-dimensional triangles are such that they share the 1-dimensional boundary, then there is a 3-dimensional simplex filling the gap extending them to a tetrahedron.